# How did Bert and Rodeick know where was Spittleworth's estate?

Tags: the-ickabog

Bert and Roderick manage to overtake Spittleworth to his estate, thanks to their riding skills. However the issue is how did they know where the estate was  ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible explanations

**[1] They asked someone**

This sounds likely. The duo probably asked someone on the way. They borrowed horses from a farmer, so it's possible they asked the farmer himself.

Spittleworth s plot might have been a secret, but his huge estate wasn't. So people probably knew where it was

**[2] Roderick know the way**

A less likely explanation ; Roderick knew the way.

{A} Major Roach was on very good terms with Spittleworth  (before his blunder) . He probably visited the estate at least once and it's possible he took his family with him, though this sounds less likely.

{B} Major Roach told the location of the estate to Roderick  after visiting it . Howeverthis too seems like a stretch.